# Span inside text input field?

Tags: email, html, textinput

Is it somehow possible to place a span as the value of a text input field?

I am making a mailing system for a website and want a nice looking receivers input field, where added receivers are contained and added to the value of input text field. At the moment i use a separate "adding field" while showing added receivers in a span-container. I want to merge these to fields together. Just like any input field in regular e-mail software.

Help would be most appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you use comma delimited instead? Or to keep your fancy formatting, use `textarea`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no, you cannot include a <span /> within an <input />.

You have a few options. You could use javascript to emulate behaviour like the email To: field. E.g. listen to key presses and handle actions like backspace after a ;.

Another option would be to make a list appear (css styled) like a textbox. Have the last <li /> contain a textbox with cleared styles. Every time the user adds a new email then insert a new <li /> before the textbox.

E.G.

html:

```
<ul class="email-textbox">
    <li>bob@email.com;</li>
    <li>jane@email.com;</li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.email-textbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 2px 4px; 
}

.email-textbox li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5px;   
}

.email-textbox input {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

javascript (jQuery, can change to vanilla)

```
$(function () {
    $('.email-textbox').find('input').focus();
});
```

You will need to extend this javascript to include a keypress handler etc, but it gives the general idea.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UeTDw/1/

Any option will require some javascript however.

If you can use jQuery, you could check out [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to layer a text input on top of a div that is styled to look like a text input.

```
<div id="fake-input">
    <span class="input-item">John Doe</span>
    <span class="input-item">Jane Deere</span>
    <input id="receiver-input" type="text" />
</div>
```

You can strip all styling off of receiver-input, and add borders, background colors, and such to fake-input so that it appears to be a text field. When a receiver is added, you can create a new input-item span and append it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Input text fields are typically used to accept raw text input. Attempting to wrap input text inside of a text field opens you to user error and potential difficulties with parsing data if the person is able to manipulate the tags.

Personally I would suggest keeping your current method but enabling some form of AJAX support to make things more dynamic and less error-prone to the user.

(My $0.02)

Answer (score 0):

**[TextExtjs](http://textextjs.com/)** is probably what you want. It's a jquery plugin for allowing removable tags with autocompletion etc in a textarea.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388294/creating-a-span-in-an-input-field-like-facebook-messages) is a related SO discussion - where I found this plugin - on mimicking the similar behavior found in some inputs on facebook.