# Creating a span in an input field like Facebook messages

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

All,
I'm trying to create the same type of functionality that works with the Facebook messages. I'd like to basically have a list of spans (i'm guessing they do something like that) in an input textbox followed by the little to close it out.

Does anyone know how to create something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the tag and autocomplete textfield. You might want to check the plugin called chosen:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

or, this plugin, I think it's more relevant:

http://textextjs.com/

Comment: I believe chosen is the best option. It looks nice and it works exactly as facebook readers of message input, and it has some extra features.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually an `<input>`. It's actually a list `<ul>` with a leading `<input>` for typing. Whatever you type, it appends to the list behind it, depending on the auto complete options.

there are several attempts to do this, found here:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/facebook-style-input-box