# telerik mvc combobox highlight specific words

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jcombobox, telerik-mvc

my application is asp.net MVC3.  I am using Telerik MVC combobox; I need to highlight a specific word in the dropdownlist, here is my script:

```
 highlightText(document.getElementById('Cword').value);

function highlightText(htext) {
    var str = document.getElementById("ComboBox-input").innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(htext, '<span style="color:blue;">' + htext + '</span>');
    document.getElementById("ComboBox-input").innerHTML= str;
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work, I check same script on a div and it worked.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach is not working because you are trying to insert span element into an input element which is not possible. Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499163/span-inside-text-input-field

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer in which specfic combo values are highlighted.

[Telerik Combo Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986540/telerik-combo-background)

Get the index of that value using above approch after access use

```
$("#combobox").select(index);
```