# how to change the color of the value in textfield using tags <span> in ext js

Tags: css, extjs, colors

How to specify tags in the value of the textfield in ext js.
my code:

```
var myText = new Ext.form.TextField({
                readOnly: true,
                id: "key",
                cls:"overflowText",
                value: '<span style="color:red">'+name+'</span>',

            });
```

This doesnt apply color to the value.How can i do it?

Comment: really we can add span in textfield value? better you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499163/span-inside-text-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it happens because style rule is missing semicolon at the end? So it should be `<span style="color:red;">`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fieldCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-fieldCls) property, you shouldn't need the span.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ios)

```
// Style
<style>
    .overflowText {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

// Code
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            width: 500,
            height: 300,
            title: "FormLayout Panel",
            layout: 'form',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            bodyPadding: 5,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'first',
                fieldCls: 'overflowText',
                allowBlank: false
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'last'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Company',
                name: 'company'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                vtype: 'email'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'DOB',
                name: 'dob',
                xtype: 'datefield'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Age',
                name: 'age',
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100
            }, {
                xtype: 'timefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Time',
                name: 'time',
                minValue: '8:00am',
                maxValue: '6:00pm'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually I want only some part of the value field to be colored not the complete value. if i have two strings one string of one color and other of different color. That why I wanted to know If we can use any tags in the value field.

Comment: I beleive you can yes, but you may be better using an [editor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Editor) instead